# Mac suddenly restarted

Tags: mac

Out of the blue, my Mac screen took on a pink hue and spontaneously initiated a reboot. This curious occurrence has repeated itself on a couple of occasions. After each reboot, I received a series of error messages. Could anyone kindly lend their expertise to help me decipher what might have transpired during these incidents? Your insights are much appreciated.

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002595e6cc): "skr.ubft.fsw_2:2": skr 

0x0xfffffe24d8098400 sg 0x0xfffffe167118bea0 (idx 1) unable to satisfy mandatory allocation

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0xff
OS release type: User
OS version: 23A344
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.0.0: Fri Sep 15 14:41:34 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.1.13~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 7CD3C0485714106B76F60CFF2DED0D9D
Kernel UUID: 9D9158F9-0E6D-30C0-BBA9-519175145599
Boot session UUID: D29FC2BA-A373-42C6-A58D-BFC86FE6907A
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.1.1
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001ce3c000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0023e40000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001ce44000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe0023e48000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x000000001e338000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe002533c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x17cff1b97da
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x653b94aa 0x0000f8a2
  Sleep   : 0x653f4540 0x0007dc1b
  Wake    : 0x653f47b6 0x0000535f
  Calendar: 0x653f5679 0x0008fef6

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xfffffe1006678000 - 0xfffffe3006678000
  . VM    : 0xfffffe1006678000 - 0xfffffe14d3344000
  . RO    : 0xfffffe14d3344000 - 0xfffffe166ccdc000
  . GEN0  : 0xfffffe166ccdc000 - 0xfffffe1b399a8000
  . GEN1  : 0xfffffe1b399a8000 - 0xfffffe2006674000
  . GEN2  : 0xfffffe2006674000 - 0xfffffe24d3340000
  . GEN3  : 0xfffffe24d3340000 - 0xfffffe29a000c000
  . DATA  : 0xfffffe29a000c000 - 0xfffffe3006678000
  Metadata: 0xfffffe491d184000 - 0xfffffe4925184000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffe4925184000 - 0xfffffe492677c000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e5840
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe00254e703c
TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xfffffe24d2d7d090  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x0000000000000000 }
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe00253cfc08, LR=0xfffffe00253cfc08, FP=0xfffffe53503dfef0
CORE 2: PC=0x00000001943fb6b0, LR=0x00000001944088d8, FP=0x000000016b911470
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe00254e1f40, LR=0xfffffe00254e1f3c, FP=0xfffffe534ef2fe80
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe00253cfc08, LR=0xfffffe00253cfc08, FP=0xfffffe534faabef0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe00253cfc08, LR=0xfffffe00253cfc08, FP=0xfffffe534f19fef0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe00253cfc08, LR=0xfffffe00253cfc08, FP=0xfffffe534ebabef0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe00253cfc08, LR=0xfffffe00253cfc08, FP=0xfffffe5350387ef0
Compressor Info: 15% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 9% of segments limit (OK) with 3 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xfffffe1b3994e6d8: 0 pages, 483 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe24d2d7d090, backtrace: 0xfffffe534ef5ed30, tid: 1517
          lr: 0xfffffe0025395264  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5edc0
          lr: 0xfffffe00254ed490  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5ede0
          lr: 0xfffffe00254de4c8  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5ee50
          lr: 0xfffffe00254dc93c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5ef40
          lr: 0xfffffe0025343aa4  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5ef50
          lr: 0xfffffe0025394b44  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f300
          lr: 0xfffffe0025ba554c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f320
          lr: 0xfffffe002595e6cc  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f390
          lr: 0xfffffe002595ef2c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f430
          lr: 0xfffffe002595ab3c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f520
          lr: 0xfffffe002595a504  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f570
          lr: 0xfffffe002595a2ec  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f640
          lr: 0xfffffe00259b8490  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5f680
          lr: 0xfffffe002598fe6c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fa20
          lr: 0xfffffe002598ecf0  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fa70
          lr: 0xfffffe0025979cd0  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fb20
          lr: 0xfffffe002597a9f4  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fba0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025998ae8  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fbf0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025999a40  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fc30
          lr: 0xfffffe0027b8f984  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fc90
          lr: 0xfffffe0027b8f364  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fcd0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027b8fb80  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fd00
          lr: 0xfffffe0025f7287c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fe50
          lr: 0xfffffe0025fc3a38  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fea0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025fc3d8c  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fec0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025aa2490  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5fef0
          lr: 0xfffffe0025aa3040  fp: 0xfffffe534ef5ff20
          lr: 0xfffffe002534ced8  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily(1.0)[C5DC6F78-501F-3676-A37C-EFA4F11E845B]@0xfffffe0027b74c20->0xfffffe0027bae65b
            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[201C96F6-82E0-317A-8073-8712E306A09A]@0xfffffe0027ad18d0->0xfffffe0027ad535f
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[10B50316-8179-3B65-804D-7B518374D079]@0xfffffe0027a64200->0xfffffe0027a84847
         com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe(1.0)[1CF56E83-7FFF-3191-B214-566564CB3B2F]@0xfffffe0025f645e0->0xfffffe0025fc6f2b
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[46E2D12C-E153-3DD2-999C-FFF05EC8A75E]@0xfffffe0025d3bad0->0xfffffe0025d8e3b7
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore(1.0.0)[BAA4C353-1FA3-307D-83D7-5FC0AD0F59AC]@0xfffffe0025fc6f30->0xfffffe00261dc367
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService(1)[6D4EEA8C-70C9-3BA5-84BA-1F6FCD821167]@0xfffffe002621ff10->0xfffffe0026220213
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE(1)[93D0212A-30A3-3425-9607-1C23BD73AAAE]@0xfffffe002644edc0->0xfffffe002646cd9f
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL(1)[9C6A5C1D-A8B4-3413-BE08-0E66152A2D89]@0xfffffe0026922390->0xfffffe002693c437
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial(1.0)[70810D97-03F1-317C-AD07-75C3586328E1]@0xfffffe002693c440->0xfffffe002694ed7f
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader(1.0.0)[F625579A-BC0D-3418-A79C-E6F8F0C29865]@0xfffffe0027979b00->0xfffffe002798bf63
            dependency: com.apple.driver.corecapture(1.0.4)[0E404240-3C29-380E-8FA7-A5E51542BB38]@0xfffffe002847d900->0xfffffe00284a73af
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily(1)[8FD734DB-BBBF-3457-A09A-94E006AA4870]@0xfffffe0026fe53e0->0xfffffe0026fed1cb
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.13.0)[06D3FB63-356F-357F-8FF8-33DE389AD567]@0xfffffe002729c3b0->0xfffffe002748d49b
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[10B50316-8179-3B65-804D-7B518374D079]@0xfffffe0027a64200->0xfffffe0027a84847
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[977B471E-9343-3995-86C8-4BACD3410824]@0xfffffe0027ad5360->0xfffffe0027b02bef
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily(1.0)[C5DC6F78-501F-3676-A37C-EFA4F11E845B]@0xfffffe0027b74c20->0xfffffe0027bae65b

last started kext at 14061517557: com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0 (addr 0xfffffe0024811bd0, size 5912)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 7400.26
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   300.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.filesystems.nfs   1
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  2235.0.13
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  650.0.2
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  700.46
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   700.46
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    6.1.1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   300.15
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler   1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  703.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   732
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.AGXG13G   275.6
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   272.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   404
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive 1
com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial   6.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1200.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 7400.26
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    7400.42
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  7400.42
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   7400.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleUVDMDriver    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  300.14
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   7400.34
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  7400.34
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    7400.34
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.IOHIDPowerSource   1
com.apple.driver.AppleCallbackPowerSource   1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSyntheticGameController   11.0.24
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    275.6
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  275.6
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   700.46
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 700.46
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    300.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1200.91
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    8.24.1
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   7.23.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 93
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.81
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.3
com.apple.iokit.IOPortFamily    1.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.13.0
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL    1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    800.11
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 300.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1200.91
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    597
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    556
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  240
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   492
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   492
com.apple.driver.AppleRSMChannel    1
com.apple.iokit.IORSMFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleLockdownMode  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUVDM  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   352.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 300.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs    300.1
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  71.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  5.0.0
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.Compression   1.0
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    14.0



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 400106 (Uncompressed 1018112) **
```

Comment: Run [EtreCheck](https://www.etrecheck.com/en/index.html) (3rd party but well-respected app, freeware version is enough) & [Apple Hardware Test/Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/HT202731) & report back any significant finding.

Comment: The few tea leaves I can read in that panic dump suggest it crashed while the networking stack was doing something, possibly over Wi-Fi. But that's something that happens all the time, so it might not be a software bug, but possibly a hardware failure (perhaps a bad RAM chip or a problem in the processor cache). I second the notion that you should run hardware diags.